# how to merge two associative arrays php

Tags: php, angularjs, arrays, associative-array

First off, there are already many questions on stackoverflow with the same title, but not one of them has been able to solve my problem because they are in some ways different.

So, I have two arrays,
Here's one:

```
  array:4 [
      0 => array:5 [
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "view-reports"
        "display_name" => "Reports"
        "created_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
      ]
      1 => array:5 [
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "add-user"
        "display_name" => "Add new user"
        "created_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
      ]
      2 => array:5 [
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "manage-users"
        "display_name" => "Manage users"
        "created_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
      ]
      3 => array:5 [
        "id" => 4
        "name" => "add-role"
        "display_name" => "Add role"
        "created_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
      ]
  ]
```

and here is the other:

```
  array:2 [
      1 => array:5 [
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "add-user"
        "display_name" => "Add new user"
        "created_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
      ]
      3 => array:5 [
        "id" => 4
        "name" => "add-role"
        "display_name" => "Add role"
        "created_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
        "updated_at" => "2016-11-20 17:26:47"
      ]
  ]
```

They are selected from the same database table `permissions` but the first set is all the permissions on the `permissions` table while the second array is the list of permissions already assigned to a particular role.

Now I am trying to implement an interface where all the permissions will be displayed with a checkbox against each permission. The value of a checkbox will be `checked` if that permission is already assigned to a given role and `unchecked` if not yet assigned to that role. On this interface, I can then assign permissions to users using ajax when a particular checkbox is checked or unchecked by the admin.

In order to accomplish this, I tried to modify the arrays so that the second array that is already assigned to a role carry an additional key-value pair: `check` whose value is 1.

```
  /**
* return all permissions related to a role
*/
public function getPermissions($name){
    $role = Role::where('name', $name)->first();

    $role_perms = $role->perms->toArray();//permissions already assigned to role
    $all_perms = Permission::all()->toArray();//all permissions on permissions table

    $result[] = null;
    foreach ($all_perms as $all_perm) {
        if ($this->permFound($name, $all_perm)) {
            $all_perm['check'] = 1;
            array_push($result, $all_perm);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
* check if $perm is a permission already assigned.
*/
public function permFound($name, $perm){
    $role = Role::where('name', $name)->first();
    $role_perms = $role->perms->toArray(); //a role's permissions

    $flag = false;
    foreach ($role_perms as $role_perm) {
        if (array_diff_assoc($perm, $role_perm)) {
            $flag = false; 
        }
    }  
    return $flag; 
}
```

The above code is meant to loop through all the `permissions` and mark the ones already assigned to a role as `check => 1`.

On the HTML interface, using angularjs (you don't need to know angularjs to understand this piece of code) i display the roles in a loop as follows:

```
<tr ng-repeat="permission in permissions">
    <td><input type="checkbox" {{permission.check == 1 : checked ? ''}} ></td>
</tr>
```

But this code returns all permissions instead and when i inspect in the console, the `check => 1` part is not available.

What could i be doing wrong? Or is there a simpler way to do it?

Thanks for your time and for any ideas.